# SVN: How to get "Next 100" revisions

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, sharpsvn

TortoiseSVN's 'SVN Show Log" command shows the most recent 100 commits. There's also a 'Next 100' button to show the next 100 commits. Even for a single file, where Tortoise might have to go back years to find 100 revisions, it's very fast, usually less than a second.

I'm trying to understand how to do this using either SharpSVN or svn.exe. I don't see any variant of `svn log` or `SharpSVN.SvnClient.GetLog` that allows me to retrieve commits for individual files in batches of arbitrary size N. Clearly I could get all the commits, or keep going backwards until I've collected N entries, but that defeats the whole purpose, which is to efficiently show only recent changes, and then go backwards only if the user wants more.

Anyone? TIA.

[edited for clarity]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-r` switch like this:

```
svn log -r <start_revision>:<end_revision>
```

Example:

```
svn log -r 1000:1100
```

More about it in here: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.revision

Comment: Right, but all or most of those revisions would probably be for other files, so I might have to do that many times to get 100 revisions for a specific file. That's what I'm trying to avoid. Tortoise is able to do this in less than a second, so I'm pretty sure that's not what it's doing. It would take much longer. (I've edited the question to try to make this more clear.)

Comment: Then you have to combine this command with `-l` option to limit your results. Something like: `svn log -l 100 -r 1:HEAD`. Then just change the HEAD revision to the latest visible to pull another 100.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
svn log -l 10 -r <end_revision>:<start_revision>
```

Will get revisions from end_revision to end revision-10